# GStreamer Example from Official Tutorial does not Run on Ubuntu 18.04 with GStreamer 1.14.1

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I installed a fresh version of Ubuntu 18.04 and I am trying to demux a single channel from a Matroska file by running the exact command from the Gstreamer documentation ( https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/gstreamer-tools.html ).

Gstreamer is current:

```
gst-launch-1.0 --version
gst-launch-1.0 version 1.14.1
GStreamer 1.14.1
https://launchpad.net/distros/ubuntu/+source/gstreamer1.0
```

The problem is that Gstreamer keeps complaining that:

```
GstMatroskaDemux:d: Delayed linking failed
```

Error:

```
gst-launch-1.0 souphttpsrc location=https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm ! matroskademux name=d d.video_00 ! matroskamux ! filesink location=sintel_video.mkv
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
Got context from element 'souphttpsrc0': gst.soup.session=context, session=(SoupSession)NULL, force=(boolean)false;
WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstMatroskaDemux:d: Delayed linking failed.
Additional debug info:
./grammar.y(510): gst_parse_no_more_pads (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstMatroskaDemux:d:
failed delayed linking pad  video_00 of GstMatroskaDemux named d to some pad of GstMatroskaMux named matroskamux0
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstSoupHTTPSrc:souphttpsrc0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(3055): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstSoupHTTPSrc:souphttpsrc0:
streaming stopped, reason not-linked (-1)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: This is a WEBM file. a matroska demuxer cannot do anything with that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually remembered that webm is doing matroska file format. The example is actually faulty/out of date. The pad naming is wrong. Instead of `00` use `0`:

```
gst-launch-1.0 souphttpsrc location=https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm ! matroskademux name=d d.video_0 ! matroskamux ! filesink location=sintel_video.mkv
```